# Visual C++ weird errors

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I copied a project I did in g++ to visual studio and it threw up a lot of errors, most of them concentrate on using the `{ a, b, c }` syntax to initialize structs.
The problem its having right now is it can't understand this:

```
struct WallPoint
{
    int x, y;
};

WallPoint p = { 0, 1 }; // error C2059: syntax error : '{'
```

or

```
WallPoint p2[] = { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 2 } }; // error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
```

Is there any compiler switch I can use to make it understand this?

Edit: The whole file that doesn't work:

```
struct WallPoint
{
    int x, y;
};

void x()
{
    WallPoint p;
    p = (WallPoint) { 0, 1 };
}

class
{
    WallPoint p[] = 
    {
        { 0, 1 },
        { 1, 2 }
    };
};

int main() { return 0; }
```

Comment: Is the definition of `p` in the global scope or inside a function?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: for the specific errors, `p` is in a function, `p2` is a `const static` in a class

Comment: Hm, are you sure it's not an ambient bug? This should really work, even [according to Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81k8cwsz.aspx)... (edited the link for 2010)

Comment: @Kerrek SB, is it c specific? cause I'm using it in c++

Comment: Works for me. Please post your real code!!

Comment: @Dani: aggregate initialization should work in all flavours of C and C++. Microsoft doesn't have a C compiler, only VC++.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: posted real code that doesn't work.

Comment: @David Heffernan: posted real code that doesn't work

Comment: Wait, so basically your real code has nothing to do with your original question, and you didn't use maximal compiler warnings either to alert you to your invalid construction??

Comment: *... where the class has no name...* (hums)

Comment: +1 @Kerrek - this question is a great example of how *not* to go about asking for help.

Answer (score 3):

You need the activate the mental switch "semicolon after class definition":

```
struct Wallpoint { int x, y; } ;
                              ^^^
```

---

Update, to answer your new, entirely different question:

Aggregate **initialization** can only be used to initialise named variables:

```
WallPoint p = { 0, 1 }; // OK
```

It can *not*  be used for assignments, or for temporaries:

```
p = { 0, 1 };            // No!
p = (WallPoint) { 0, 1 } // Nooo!

p = WallPoint{0, 1}; // New in C++11
```

Comment: (Please don't upvote any more, the OP has changed the question.)

Comment: We're upvoting because your answer was correct given the original question. The answer deserves upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `;` at the end of the structure declaration.

Comment: It is there, forgot to copy it to the question.

Comment: Then your code is fine.  The problem is somewhere else.  If you show us the actual code, we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an assignment rather than an initializer.  It should be:

```
WallPoint p = { 0, 1 };
```

I presume that in the second example the `class` is meant to be a function. If so then the initializer there is fine.

Comment: I need the assignment as I change the struct. in the second one, I'm using an initializer.

Comment: You asked why it failed. I answered that.